# how to get the app scoped id on the basis of username in facebook in java

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

Facebook API :

How to get the app-scoped id of a user on the basis of username using Facebook graph api. I have tried different ways but it gives the error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (username1)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the username in any way anymore. You can only get an App Scoped ID by authorizing that specific user and using the `/me` endpoint.

Comment: I assume that the app - scope id we are referring to here is the facebook object / user id which is used for retrieving public details of user.

Comment: How does a tool like http://www.findmyfbid.com/ work to find the userId then ? Does it just scan the page source to get the userId ?

Comment: those tools do something that is not allowed on facebook: scraping the profile page. and you don´t get an app scoped id with that, you get the "real" id, which is pointless anyway. again, you only get an app scoped id by authorizing the user and that´s the only serious way to get a user id.